# Создание отчета в файл

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.

Сабж следующий, есть форма, с определенным текстом, в который нужно вносить запланированные изменения. Ну что-то типа:

Сотрудник {XXX} получает отпуск {XXX} числа в связи с {XXX} ситуацией.

вот где {XXX} нужно внести изменения. Текст - лейбл, текстбокс - изменяемое.

С чего можно начать разработку подобной штуки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у твоего приложения несколько пользователей, то можно завести в памяти ConcurrentBag, куда скидывать записи(он потокобезопасный), и периодически в фоновом потоке сбрасывать инфу на диск.

Answer (score 0):

Храните в базе ваши переменные XXX, которые скорее всего будет заполнять администраторов из отдельной формы, и в Page_Load формы делайте select'ы к БД.

Comment: а без бдшки? программа блуждающая, делать переносную базу очень геморрно